# Unrecoverable stackoverflow error when making upcalls from JavaScript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, stack-overflow

I've encountered an "unrecoverable stack overflow error" that I can't figure out. From the [docs](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx) : *you need to create an interface object (of any class) and make it known to JavaScript by calling `JSObject.setMember()`*.

Here's the Java code sharing and using the interface object :

```
// somewhere in the code
JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("foo", new Foo()); // <-- shares
window.call("testFoo");             // <-- uses

// somewhere else
class Foo {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("baz");
    }
}
```

And here's the JavaScript code using that object :

```javascript
window.testFoo = function() {
    window.foo.bar();
}
```

It occurs if I trigger it manually like show above, or if I trigger it through some JavaScript event.

Comment: I tried it and it works for me (Java 1.8.0_11). Maybe it would help if you posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I think Foo should be public, otherwise it looks OK to me (without trying it).  The doc you link is an old blog post based on an early developer preview.  More modern documentation is available for [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/js-javafx.htm).

Comment: I like how you have used stackoverflow to get assistance recovering from an unrecoverable stackoverflow  error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was in the comments, I can't believe I've been trying everything for hours and it was a very quick fix.

Turns out that the exposed interface has to be **public**.